# Dynamic Form Elements in Access

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I am working on a project in Access 2016 and VBA, that contains a table that stores the details of students (StudentID, EnrollmentNo, Name, Center, etc) and another that contains the attendence (having fourcolumns: ID, StudentID, DateOfClass, IsPresent).

I want to create a form displaying multiple rows, each row belonging to a each student displaying (Enrollment No, Name, DateOfBirth, DateOfClass, IsPresent) and finally want to input the isPresent field using check box and then save the information for all/add new information.

Is there any way to do this ?

Here I am concerned about the form. How do I CREATE such a form (like Datasheet view) where I have a list of students column wise (with their details like enrollment number etc.) and IsPresent (check box type thing) in the next. So that If I like to input attendence in the attendance table I could just set the date and mark the checkboxes in front of students and then press a button which adds all the data to the table.

Answer (score 0):

No table of classes/subjects? Only 2 tables? You have to do data entry into Attendance. Could only create records for students that attend so the IsPresent field would not be needed. If you want record for student even if not attending then, yes, need IsPresent.

If you want to 'batch' create records for all students for a particular date, run INSERT SELECT sql action.

`INSERT INTO Attendance(StudentID, DateOfClass) SELECT StudentID, [enter date value] AS DateOfClass FROM Students;`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, It would be better not to create entry for students who are absent on a particular day.

But here I am concerned about the form. How do I CREATE such a form (like Datasheet view) where I have a list of students column wise (with their details like enrollment number etc.) and IsPresent (check box type thing) in the next. So that If I like to input attendence in the attendance table I could just set the date and mark the checkboxes in front of students and then press a button which adds all the data to the table.

Comment: Can't with a BOUND form. Can't show data for records that don't yet exist in Attendance. You have to do data entry - select student from combobox and enter date. Record is committed to table when 1. close table,query,form or 2. move to another record or 3. run code to save. Data entry for multiple records can be assisted by code that sets the date input textbox DefaultValue property.